# auto_detect_line_endings - Are there side effects?

Tags: php, csv

I'm writing a script that processes CSV's and I've discovered that setting auto_detect_line_endings seems to be the way to go to handle CSV's created on Macs.
Are there any possible downsides or side-effects to making this setting change? I couldn't seem to spot any (which begs the question, why wouldn't you always have it on?)

`ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);`

Comment: Seems like this question is out of date, ini_set only accepts strings now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only for CSV files created on ancient Macs that have \r line endings. It's not a default because such files are rare and there's a tiny performance penalty. It's safe to turn it on if you want to be as permissive as possible about the CSV files you want to process.